# 555 timer to work once per day for 30 minutes

Tags: timer

I was wondering if I could use a 555 timer to turn on a PI once per day for about 30 minutes. I want to use the 555 because it will take power from a photovoltaic source.

Comment: I'm going to say "probably not" -- but how precisely do you need to have it be at the same time every day? I would expect you would get better timing accuracy from a microcontroller, and most likely need a real-time clock (RTC) to have reasonable timing accuracy every 24 hours.

Comment: When you have very little power that is a good reason NOT to use a plain 555, but you might succeed with a C555 (CMOS version). But better use a small micro-controller and program it appropriately.

Comment: Another thing to realize is that it is very hard to get an accurate and stable over days 24hrs interval

Comment: Definitely not. This is what RTCs are for.

Comment: why not use a simple MCU?!?

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I am kinda new to electronics if you someone could tell me which microcontroller and maybe if there is a ready program for it i would be grateful

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to keep "time of day", even with a crystal-controlled timer. A 555 might be good to 1% (after adjustment) so it could gain or lose maybe 15 minutes per day. I might add that adjusting would be a monstrous PITA if you tried to use a 555 directly (and it's not that easy to get times like that out of 555- big expensive low leak capacitors and high value resistors). With a counter, you could use a much faster clock (say 1Hz), but the accuracy may still be a problem (see below).

A crystal running a microcontroller would be much better, maybe seconds or minutes per month, or a really good crystal oscillator might keep within a couple seconds a year.

If you really mean "approximately once every 24 hours" rather than at almost the same time every day then it is easier. In this case the time might be 9:00 AM one day, 9:14 the next day, 9:35 the next day etc. (the errors are cumulative).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, especially if you use one of the low-power versions - you can get one set up for a much longer timeout period than that, even.

If you want to simply turn on at sunrise for 30 minutes, your job is extremely easy. If you want it to turn on at some other hour of the day, though, you'll probably wind up using one for the initial timeout and a second one for the "on time". You can, fortunately, get two 555s in a single package.

Initial triggering (to begin either the "on time" delay) or the initial timeout delay could be driven entirely by sunrise striking the panel, generating the first voltage of the day.

Comment: I remember, many moons ago, someone using a 555 to clock an EPROM to produce 8 independent outputs that could switch on and off at any number of points in the day.

Comment: Ooo, NICE application, @carveone! I like that! You could even have demultiplexed the EPROM to get 256 different evenly-spaced "events", one about every 5-1/2 minutes based on a 24-hour full cycle.